# User's Phone Screen Size

Tags: live-wallpaper

I am writing a livewallpaper. As before, I get the user's screen width & height  at "onSurfaceChanged". Can I get the screen width & height at "onSurfaceCreated"?

Answer (score 2):

you can get screen size at anywhere you like using

```
getWallpaperDesiredMinimumWidth()/2
```

or
put

```
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager)getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
DisplayMetrics metrics;
disp = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
```

at the top of the source, and do

```
disp.getMetrics(metrics);
screenWidth = (float) metrics.widthPixels;
```